# Android SQLite with cursor

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, relational-database

In a previous post, I have not been clear enough about my problem:

I have 2 class :

```
public class Categorie {

    // Attributs
    private int identifiant;
    private String libelle;

   ...
}

public class Restaurant {

    // Attributs
    private int identifiant;
    private String nom;
    private String description;
    private List<Categorie> lesCategories;

    ...
}
```

And in SQLite :

```
CREATE TABLE Categorie
( categorie_id  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
, libelle       TEXT    NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Restaurant
( restaurant_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
, nom           TEXT    NOT NULL
, description   TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE RestaurantCategorie
( restaurant_id INTEGER NOT NULL    REFERENCES Restaurant
, categorie_id  INTEGER NOT NULL    REFERENCES Categorie
, PRIMARY KEY (restaurant_id, categorie_id)
);
```

But for create my cursor, i don't know how do it...

```
public Restaurant ConvertCursorToObject(Cursor c) { 

Restaurant restaurant= new Restaurant ( 
    c.getInt(EnseigneOpenHelper.NUM_RES_ID), 
    c.getString(EnseigneOpenHelper.NUM_RES_NOM),
    c.getString(EnseigneOpenHelper.NUM_RES_DESCRIPtion), 
    ????
); 
return restaurant; 
}

/** * Convert a cursor in Restaurant */

public Restaurant ConvertCursorToOneObject(Cursor c) { 
    c.moveToFirst(); 
    Restaurant restaurant = ConvertCursorToObject(c); 
    c.close(); 
    return restaurant ; 
}
```

This problem it's here = "????"
My constructor want an object of type List Categorie.

Answer (score 1):

Perform another query for the categories using the restaurant id you acquired from the first query. Then just build a list of categories from the results of the new cursor.